# How did std::vector<bool> come about?

Tags: c++, history, stl

Today, virtually all C++ developers agree that `std::vector<bool>` was a mistake since it is deceivingly not a container, and its use cases largely overlap with those of `std::bitset` anyway.

How did it get voted into the standard? Was it controversial at the time? What were the main supporting arguments?

Comment: Wasn't `std::vector` written before `std::bitset`?

Comment: https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool

Comment: Also, Herb Sutter writes extensively about `std::vector<bool>` [here](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/N1185.pdf) and [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1847.pdf).  I think if you dig a bit more into his writings, you'll find all of the information you need.

Comment: See also http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill09.htm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From Herb Sutter using the reference quoted:

> The vector specialization was intentionally put into the
>   standard to provide an example of how to write a proxied container. A
>   "proxied container" is a container whose objects you don't get at
>   directly; instead of giving you pointers or references to a contained
>   object, a proxied container gives you proxy objects that can be used
>   to indirectly access or manipulate a contained object. Proxied
>   collections can be useful in cases where the objects within the
>   collection cannot always be reliably accessed directly as though they
>   were in memory, as for example with a disk-based collection that
>   automatically pages pieces of itself in and out of memory under the
>   covers as needed. So the idea was to show how to make such a proxied
>   collection meet the requirements of a "container" in the sense defined
>   by the standard library.

And yes, there was discussion at the time.

> 4. For all the gory details, surf to DejaNews and do a power search for Subject="vector and bool" and Forum="*c++*". The discussions took
>      place in Jan/Feb 1997. You will also find more recent discussions from
>      people asking how to turn off the vector specialization; see the
>      end of this article for my advice.

The rest is history.
And I hate seeing an unanswered question with such good links.